# Странное поведение симулятора iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, эмулятор, testng

Тестирую приложение для iOS. Если локально собрать его в Xcode, оно нормально работает в симуляторе. Если собрать это приложение у любого из разработчиков и передать `app`-файл, без разницы как — собранный файл (пробовали разные версии, для симулятора, для устройств, устанавливали все возможные архитектуры, собирали через интерфейс Xcode и через Терминал). Устанавливать в симуляторе тоже пробовали — перетаскиванием, через Терминал, попробовали разные атрибуты. В логе ошибок нет. Приложение запускается, показывается стартовый экран и сразу сворачивается. Дальнейшие действия с ним не приводят ни к чему, приложение сворачивается. Удаление у установка приложения не помогает.

Если собрать приложение у меня, у одного разработчика оно запустится. Версия macOS у всех одинаковая — 10.15.2, Xcode тоже самый новый.
Единственная разница — у разработчика, у которого запускается, — MacBook Pro 2015 года выпуска, у остальных — 2017 года выпуска и новее.

Comment: Может что-то с IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET, PROVISIONING_PROFILE? Запускаете на той же версии симулятора (версия ОС симулятора), для которого собирался app?

Comment: Пробовали для разных версий собирать и запускать на разных версиях. В на одинаковых и на разных, так же попробовали различные устройства эмулировать ipad, iphone 8, iphone 11

Comment: Ваше утверждение об отсутствии чего-либо в логах вводит в заблуждение. Как такое может быть?

Comment: Мы сравнивали логи скомпилированного локально приложения и того, что скинул разработчик, разницы нет.

Comment: @Alexandr какие логи имеются в виду? В икскоде или в приложении Консоль? Попробуйте сравнить вывод в логе Консоли для собранного вами и полученного с другой машины билда и погуглите ошибки из Консоли, может это что-то даст

Comment: Мы сравнили все логи, xcode, консоль, так же сравнили на разных машинах, даже сравнивали файлы которые создаются при установке, все идентично

Comment: @Alexandr Если вы используете поды, и добавляете их как фреймворки, возможно какой то из фреймворков не может добавиться. 
Так же проверьте разрядность приложения в Build Settings, вдруг по какой-то причине стоит 32х для Architecture.